# Two ways to write directional derivative of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

It's well known that the derivative of the matrix exponential in direction $V$ is given by
\begin{align}
D_V(t,A)&=\int_0^t \exp((t-s)A)V\exp(sA)ds
\end{align}
In [1] they state that one can also write it as (eqn. 104)
\begin{align}
D_V(t,A)&=\int_0^t \exp(sA)V\exp((t-s)A)ds
\end{align}
Why are these equivalent?

[1] Najfeld, Igor, and Timothy F. Havel. "Derivatives of the matrix exponential and their computation." Advances in applied mathematics 16, no. 3 (1995): 321-375.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with the first integral formula, and apply the substitution $\sigma = t - s$. We find that
$$
\int_0^t \exp((t-s)A)V\exp(sA)ds = \\
\int_{\sigma(0)}^{\sigma(t)} \exp(\sigma A) V \exp((t - \sigma )A)\cdot (-1)d \sigma =\\
-\int_t^0 \exp(\sigma A)V \exp((t - \sigma A))\,d\sigma =\\
\int_0^t \exp(\sigma A)V \exp((t - \sigma A))\,d\sigma,
$$
which is the desired formula.

Comment: Thanks. I was working through it myself and got to the third line and got confused. What does an integral from 0 to t mean and why can we invert it to get its negative?

Comment: @mlstudent I'm not sure how to answer your question about what the integral "means". In general, $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = -\int_b^a f(x)\,dx$; switching the limits of an integral multiplies it by $-1$.

Comment: Actually I found a discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577675/why-change-the-sign-of-the-integral-when-switching-the-limits-of-integration.

Comment: @mlstudent This statement holds for real-valued integrals, perhaps it would be helpful to convince yourself of that simpler statement

Comment: Sorry when I said from 0 to t I meant from t to 0.